# PHP Sign-up Form Issues with Validation and Insertion

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to create a sign-up page for a large-scale website which means I'm using a lot more layers of validation then I would normally do, given this should be common practice but in this particular case more than any other situation it is imperative.

I've already written most of the code required and formatted it in an order which I believed wouldn't lead to any undefined variable errors, however, upon form submission it doesn't create a new SQL row and doesn't return any errors under the error handling areas of the form validation. In all fairness, the error handling is *quite* simple at this point and is not a final version, just what I put in place to help me debug and troubleshoot any issues which should arise.

Here's the PHP code, and the snippet of the piss-poor error handling that is supposed to output an error message if an error occurs, to re-state, this error handling isn't final.

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root2', '123', 'db');

    $signupConditionsMet = "0";

    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && isset($_POST["passwordCheck"]) && isset($_POST["birthdate"])) {
        $signupConditionsMet = "1";
        $birthGood = true;
        $passGood = false;
        $nameGood = false;
        $emailGood = false;
    }

    $usernameSearch = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");

    $userInsertion = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, passwd, birthdate, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    $nameErr = $emailErr = $passErr = $birthErr = "";
    $name = $email = $pass = $birth = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = $_POST["username"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"];
        $birthdate = $_POST["birthdate"];
        $passCheck = $_POST["passwordCheck"];
    }

    if ($signupConditionsMet === "1"){
        function test_input($name) {
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-z\d_]{2,15}$/i",$name)) {
                $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            } else {
                $nameGood = true;
                return $name;
                echo "did name ez";
            }
        }

        function test_input2($email){
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
            } else {
                $emailGood = true;
                return $email;
                echo "did email ez";
            }
        }

        function test_input3($password){
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-z\d_]{2,15}$/",$pass)) {
                $passErr = "Invalid password format";
            } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-z\d_]{2,15}$/",$passCheck)){
                $passErr = "Invalid password check format";
            } else if ($_POST["password"] !== $_POST["passwordCheck"]){
                $passErr = "Passwords do not match";
            } else {
                $passwd2 = AES_ENCRYPT($_POST["password"], 'mysecretstring');
                $passwdGood = true;
                return $passwd2;
                echo "did pass ez";
            }
        }
    }

    if (($signupConditionsMet === "1") && ($birthGood === true) && ($nameGood === true) && ($passwdGood === true) && ($emailGood === true)) {
        if ($usernameSearch->execute(array($_POST['username']))) {
            while ($row = $usernameSearch->fetch()) {
                if (!empty($row['id'])) {
                    $creationError = "This username is already taken";
                } else { 
                    $userInsertion->bindParam(1, $name);
                    $userInsertion->bindParam(2, $passwd2);
                    $userInsertion->bindParam(3, $birthdate);
                    $userInsertion->bindParam(4, $email);
                    $userInsertion->execute();
                    header('Location: userlanding.php');
                }
            }
        }
    } 

/* PHP inside the HTML to output errors */

        <?php if ($signupConditionsMet === "1") { echo "all inputs received"; echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];} else { echo "drats, they weren't all there"; echo $name; echo $email; echo $birthdate; echo $pass; echo $passCheck;}?>
        <?php if ($passErr) { echo $passErr;} else if ($nameErr) { echo $nameErr;} else if ($emailErr) { echo $emailErr;} else if ($birthErr) { echo $birthErr;} ?>
```

Disregarding the previously admitted terrible error handling, I can't seem to wrap my head around why it doesn't work in its current form. It returns (from the client-side reporting) that all inputs were received and there isn't any fatal errors thrown from running the PHP code. In addition, the second client-side code which prints any errors doesn't print anything either, implying that all functions operated correctly, however, the echos at the bottom of the input tests don't echo the strings they've been assigned, implying those didn't work, but there was no errors. Hmm. Perhaps I'm missing something blatantly obvious regarding my syntax but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: There's a lot of strange things going on in here, especially the part where functions are defined inside of an `if`. These functions have meaningless names. Consider `test_password` instead of `test_input3` as `input3` is not anything you're dealing with. Also try and prepare queries if/when you need them, not just because, and keep the query as close as possible to its execution point so you don't fire the wrong query by accident.

Comment: PHP also has booleans, `true` and `false`, which you should always use instead of things like `"0"` and `"1"`. A boolean can also be used like `if ($boolean)` without having to do `if ($boolean === true)` or anything redundant.

Comment: Well the point of nesting it inside an if statement is to only define the functions and run them if the form has been submitted, if I just defined them outside of one then it would return errors as those variables do not exist. Correct me if I'm mistaken. For the booleans, that was what I originally formatted the condition met variables under but during the debugging phase I was wondering if I'd somehow defined them wrong so changed them to verify they were not the source of the issue.

Comment: Normally you don't conditionally define functions, you define them and conditionally call them. Unless you define functions with arguments for all the data they might need then you're creating closure functions which is completely overkill for a problem as simple as this.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files, as well as demonstrate code patterns to use.

Comment: You made a good point, I've since transferred development over to Laravel.